# symfony smtp - Connection could not be established with host

Tags: php, linux, symfony, smtp

I am trying to send a message (smtp) via symfony.

```
$ transport = \ Swift_SmtpTransport ('my_host', 587, 'ssl')
-> SetUserName ('my_username')
-> SetPassword ('my_password');
```

I get the message [Connection could not be established with host]
The access data is certainly correct, eg giving the same data in eg Thunderbird everything is ok.

Initially, I thought I had an error in the script, but the script works fine (giving a different server everything is ok).

Is it a fault in server configuration?
Thank you.
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can see found it the documentation (I typed "symfony send email" in google ;) ) https://symfony.com/doc/master/email.html

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
    ->setFrom('send@example.com')
    ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
            'emails/registration.html.twig',
            array('name' => $name)
        ),
        'text/html'
    )
;

//then use the mailer service to send it 
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

The configuration of swiftmailer is in the configuration files as described here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html